# On upper bounding a sum of integrals performed on annulli.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

I am trying to read *Exploring the toolkit of Jean Bourgain*, a beautiful article by Terrence Tao, that can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06736.pdf).

Given $0 <\epsilon < 1/2$, $J = J(\epsilon)$ a sufficiently large natural number, and a sequence of scales  $0 < t_J < \dots < t_1 \le 1 $ with $t_{j+1} \le t_j/ 2$ for all $1 \le j \le J$, Tao considers the integral (at page 6)

$$ \int_{  \delta/ t_j \le|\xi|\le  1/ \delta t_j}| \hat{1}_B(\xi)  |^2  d \xi \tag{1} $$

where  $0< \delta= \delta(\epsilon) \le 1/2$ is a small quantity to be chosen later, $B \subset [-1,1]^2$ and $\hat{1}_B$ is the Fourier transform of the indicator function $1_B$, i.e.,

$$  \hat{1}_B(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 1_B(x) e^{2\pi i x \xi} dx . $$

Tao then remarks that the integral in $(1)$ can be crudely upper bounded with the help of Plancherel's theorem

$$ \int_{  \delta/ t_j \le|\xi|\le  1/ \delta t_j}| \hat{1}_B(\xi)  |^2  d \xi \lesssim \int_{  \mathbb{R}^2}| \hat{1}_B(\xi)  |^2  d \xi =\int_{  \mathbb{R}^2}  1_B(x)   d x = |B|$$

However, because of the lacunarity hypothesis $t_{j+1} \le t_j/ 2$ the annulli $\{  \delta/ t_j \le|\xi|\le  1/ \delta t_j \}$ only overlap with multiplicity $O(\log{\frac{1}{\delta}})$ so we can actually obtain

$$ \sum_{j=1}^J \int_{  \delta/ t_j \le|\xi|\le  1/ \delta t_j}| \hat{1}_B(\xi)  |^2  d \xi \lesssim \log{\frac{1}{\delta}} |B|.$$

What does Tao mean with "overlap with multiplicity $O(\log{\frac{1}{\delta}})$" and how does one then show the last inequality?

EDIT:

I believe I might be on the right path to understanding what Tao means with "overlap with multiplicity $O(\log{\frac{1}{\delta}})$"

Take $a_1,\dots,a_m$ integers that all lie between $1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $m  \in \mathbb{N}, (m<n)$.
We can partition them into at most $\log_2n$ sets such that any two $a_i$ in the same cell of the partition are within a factor of $2$ of each other.

I think that Tao might be using a similar idea to say that given that
$ t_{j+1} \le t_j/ 2 $ there are a maximum $O( \log_2{\frac{1}{\delta}} ) $  partitions before they start to overlap.

( maybe "begin to overlap with multiplicity $O(\log_2{\frac{1}{\delta}})$" could have been clearer).

In any case, I am still unsure if this is correct (plus there would be some details to fill in) so any help or nod of approval would be much appreciated.